# "Blobbing Effect" in Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

How could one re-create this "blobbing-off" effect in animation nodes?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a *Ping Pong* repeated time as the scale of one of the meta balls as follows:

[image: Node]

You can also evaluate the output at some interpolation to get more custom animation.